Strange -200 "voting reversed", -426 "voting corrected" yesterday - a glitch?
At some point today, I looked at my "chalice" icon, and noticed that yesterday, I lost 200 reputation. The cause: "Serial voting was reveresed". I scratched my head, as over the past several days, I don't remember that many upvotes, nor upvotes on related questions/answers - something that might indicate serial voting.
So, I went to my reputation history page, here (screenshot below), to look at the details. Again, not something which is obviously serial-upvoting; but I did see something quite strange: The "voting corrected" entry for yesterday is -426, not -200. Is this as sort of a... cap on reputation reduction?
Anyway, both figures are weird to me. Could this possibly be a glitch of some kind?
Note: Just to clarify - if I have indeed been serially-upvoted, perhaps at an earlier point in time, I'm not contesting the correction. I'm just wondering if what I'm seeing makes sense.


@SecurityHound: So, you're saying it's not about serial voting after all, just user deletion? In the past, I've seen this kind of correction as "user was deleted"...

I suspect, @einpoklum , that the user was using votes against content you had provided to also hide illegitimate votes, so those votes were rolled back first and then the user deleted.

It's only -218. I think you didn't refresh the page after load.

@SecurityHound https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

You're running into this bug Why do reputation changes listed in the "Time" view on the profile page view show large values?. Anything with yellow background (new changes) is calculated wrong. Refresh and you'd get seen items (white background).

Serial voting rarely happens in a single day. Those voting reversals are pretty much always spanning a long period of voting fraud.

For the record, no user deletion was involved here, either before or after the vote reversal.

As @VLAZ points out, this seems to be a manifestation of this bug:
Why do reputation changes listed in the "Time" view on the profile page view show large values?
and after I reload the page (so that these entries are white), I see less discrepant values: -200 and -18:

That's still not exactly the same as the "Recent Achievement" listing, but it's better...
Of course, now there's the matter of why the two different reductions and whether they're related, but I suppose that would be a different question.

I see 23 reversed votes to your account, which I guess, based on the total of 218 rep, must have been 22 upvotes and 1 downvote. The mod tools (in a different view) show it as one reversal. As for why it's shown as two separate reversals, I have a guess. A hint is that your actual reputation loss was in fact 200 (you went from 126819 to 126619). Viewing your reputation page logged out, I see only the -200, suggesting that the -18 is on deleted posts. This used to be displayed with a red highlight to make it clear(er), but possibly that broke at some point.

@RyanM: It would be nice if the listing would indicate that it's on deleted post, and maybe put the number in parentheses, or something.

I agree.  The functionality appears to have regressed, where at least previously it had a color indication.  It seems like a bug (plus the longstanding larger bug that the reputation page is ~always wrong the first time it's loaded).
